# JSch to check if a file is created and return true

Tags: java, shell, jboss, jsch

I am using JSch to push a WAR file to deployments folder of JBoss running on a remote machine. I need to identify whether the .deployed file is getting created to make sure the WAR got successfully deployed. Based on this I need to mark the process as success. Any clue on how to understand if the WAR.deployed file is created using JSch exec channel. I can make this work using sftp channel.Since the remote machine only supports sudo su, I am forced to use exec channel.

Comment: Why do you want/need to use "exec" channel? Wouldn't SFTP (channel) be more appropriate for the task?

Comment: i dont see an option to do sudo using sftp channel. The remote host only has sudo su access.

Comment: Well, that's a constraint you need to mention in your question.

Comment: thanks Martin for pointing out. I have updated the question.